# How to find linkless mentions of my website?

Tags: seo, backlinks

Recently I noticed some mentions of my Website, or a whole story but without a link.

I was wondering is there a way to search for my brand name and filter for pages which do not link to my website?

I am aware of Google alerts and Yahoo Pipes, but it seems those will only work for the future, but not for old mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This search works pretty well on Google for my site

```
example.com -link:example.com -inurl:example.com
```

Comment: thats interesting. I cant locate the websites i know dont have links, and im getting websites as result which do have a link. Do you happen to know if I can use wildcard in this like -link:*example.com*?

Comment: For my site it is finding plenty of sites that mention but don't link to my site, but it's certainly not perfect.  Google doesn't really support "link:" queries that include other search terms.  They do this on purpose to make it hard to game their search algorithm.

Comment: bleh - i guess I have to write a nasty pregmatch type crawler and check those 56k pages for no links. good times.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ahrefs.com`, they have launched a tool which allows you to find sites that mentioned your brand.